# Restrict users to access my Hard drives

Tags: networking, windows-8

how to restrict user access C$ share through RUN in windows 8 ,I want to prevent other user to access my Hard drives through command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

> DISCLAIMER: Deleting Admin Shares in a productive/enterprise environment will render certain services unusable.

I normally turn off the Admin shares with the following registry settings:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters]
"AutoShareWks"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters]
"AutoShareWks"=dword:00000000
```

Reboot after performing above registry modifications.

Then using an Administrative account on my computer I would run the following commands to delete the default shares:

```
net share C$ /delete >nul
net share ADMIN$ /delete >nul
net share IPC$ /delete >nul
```

After deleting the default share I would create a dummy location like `C:\work\shares`and create sub-directories for each previous Admin Share:

```
C:\work\shares\Admin
C:\work\shares\C
```

After creating the directories I'll go ahead and create **new** shares so that Administrators can access these blank/empty shares:

```
net share C$=C:\Work\Shares\c >nul
net share ADMIN$=C:\Work\Shares\Admin >nul
```

As previously stated in my disclaimer, performing these tasks in certain environments will render enterprise products useless.

Answer (score 0):

Create limited user accounts for other users.. By default limited do not have access to admin shares like c$ ipc$ etc..

Answer (score 0):

Network access to administrative shares only possible for users belonging to Administrators group on your computer.

1. If your computer is in a domain - remove personal accounts from the
   Administrators group.
2. If your computer is in a workgroup, check (and, if necessary,
   change) the passwords of users, members of the Administrators group

   - if they coincide with passwords the same users on adjacent computers in the network - they will have access to administrative shares.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used this to disable all the lame x$ shares:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters]
"AutoShareWks"=dword:00000000
```